# resolv.conf to localhost

Tags: networking, 18.04, resolv.conf

For about 2 hours I've been banging my head against a wall trying to get /etc/resolv.conf to use 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.53

I've just finished grep -r on my entire partition and cannot find where this damn file is coming from. Whenever I restart the service it defaults back to 127.0.0.53

This is actually just to get a dnsmasq (running in docker) to be a pass-through DNS.

Comment: Read `man resiolvconf`

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking then it appears to be compiled in to the `systemd-resolved` binary (specifically, the value of `INADDR_DNS_STUB` in the `resolved-dns-stub.h` file)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid INADDR_DNS_STUB?

Comment: Also @waltinator, I did. I could not find actionable information. If you know where there is for bionic 18.04, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @steeldriver Please see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for input. I tried that, sadly I couldn't get it to work so cannot confirm. Please see my reply on your answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ubuntu since 17.10 (possibly) now uses [netplan](https://netplan.io/) by default to provide it's DNS [source](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/).

My Default Ubuntu (bionic) looks like this

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

This is why I later found `NetworkManager` through it's X/GTK frontend to be a suitable place to set the DNS (although I also did not know about nmcli). Apparently renderers supported so far are `NetworkManager` and `networkd`, although it's noted [1](https://netplan.io/examples#network-manager) that only `NetworkManager` supports WiFi.

I've yet to find a place to set this up so that it can work for all interfaces like the old method of editing `/etc/resolv.conf`, which doesn't work in vanilla 18.04 (maybe could, but it's a lot of work, I'm end-goal oriented).

Comment: networkd does support wireless interfaces, but it's much easier using NetworkManager. You should **never** manually edit /etc/resolv.conf. Use the GUI to set DNS servers.

Comment: I'm not manually editing `/etc/resolv.conf` because it doesn't bloody well work in 18.04 vanilla. I've specifically stated I do exactly what you've advised me to do. Our difference of opinion is that I'm unhappy about needing to use a GUI to do that

Comment: See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083656/how-to-add-an-address-to-dns/1083666#1083666) and look at tudor's answer for how to do it via cli.

Answer (score 0):

pre-note: **never** manually edit /etc/resolv.conf

127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf comes from dnsmasq.

127.0.0.53 in /etc/resolv.conf comes from systemd-resolved.

dnsmasq and systemd-resolved should normally not run at the same time... as they tend to step on each others toes.

If you want dnsmasq to run, you have to tell systemd-resolved to back off, like so...

```
sudo pico /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

Change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Hi, this is something I ran, however it did not resolve the issue, and in-fact crashed DNS. This is a vanilla bionic. Can you confirm this works on your machine? On mine it required two settings in order to free up port 53
`DNSStubListener=no` and `DNSStubHandler=no`

It's got all updates installed on the system.

Comment: @MrMesees After changing DNSStubListener, did you reboot the system? I don't know about DNSStubHandler... where do you see that? Edit/update your question with `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I did. I also attempted restarting the service. Also I tried disabling the service before stop, then enabling and starting.

Comment: Please answer my `ls` question. Use @heynnema in comments to me, or I may miss them. Thanks.