# How to add an address to DNS

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).

And I want to add `172.26.5.14` to system DNS addresses.

I searched and found some solutions like:

- Add to `/etc/resolv.conf`. But data removed neither ***system*** or ***network-manager*** restart.
- Add to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` or `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`. It's not working and not shown in the `nmcli device show enp0s31f6 | grep IP4.DNS` result.

How do I add permanently to DNS servers?

Comment: Do `sudo nmcli con mod help` to see how to use it!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, nmcli not known 'enp0s31f6'

Comment: Use `sudo nmcli con show` to see the interface names on your system!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to go to

Settings -> Network -> LAN Interface (Cog Symbol) -> IPv4 Settings (tab) -> Additional DNS Servers

If you must do it from the command line, then you can type:

```
sudo nmcli con mod enp0s31f6 +ipv4.dns "172.26.5.14"
```

update with:

```
sudo nmcli con up "enp0s31f6"
```

Comment: When run first command show error: 
Error: unknown connection 'enp0s31f6'.

Comment: I use:
sudo nmcli con mod 'MY-UUID' +ipv4.dns "172.26.5.14",
and it work, Thanks all

Comment: See `sudo nmcli con mod help` for more information.
In manual help say use `+` for appending instead of override.

Answer (score 0):

On servers, edit `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses: [10.10.10.253/24]
            gateway4: 10.10.10.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [127.0.0.1,127.0.0.53]
```

Replace with your own addresses.

Then

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: This .yaml script requires `renderer: networkd`, and probably `dhcp4: no`. And the proper terminal commands should be `sudo netplan --debug generate`, **then** `sudo netplan apply`.

Comment: No, you don't need dhcp4: no if you are setting a static IP.

Comment: You still need a `renderer` line that denotes `NetworkManager` or `networkd`. You should update your answer.

Comment: No you don't, and I don't need to do that. I am looking at several servers right now in front of me, including an instance on digitalocean, what you see in the answer is exactly what I have, on a whole farm, with only difference of the actual IPs. This is real world data.

Comment: Here is another example, from one of my private servers on another private network.
https://pastebin.com/4RiD3F2R

Comment: Look at https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: ps: I wonder if this is different on servers, vs Ubuntu desktop machines with both NetworkManager and systemd-networkd?

Comment: Maybe it is different on desktops. Not sure. All I can tell you that we manage thousands of servers, hundreds of them successfully reprovisioned to 18.04 and that's how netplan is implemented, in production. My home lab has the same and my digitalocean instance is the same too.

Comment: Yes, the examples list networkd, but I guess that is playing safe.